# What do you call that part of the muscle that connects directly to the bone?

Tags: human-anatomy, muscles

When you open up a chicken leg or a clam and you remove the meat, there is this little part that is connected to the bone and is not easily scraped off.

What is this part called and what mechanism does it use to connect to the bone or the shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [tendon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendon) is the part of the muscle that connects directly to the bone.

> A tendon (or sinew) is a tough band of fibrous connective tissue that usually connects muscle to bone and is capable of withstanding tension. Tendons are similar to ligaments and fasciae; all three are made of collagen. Ligaments join one bone to another bone; fasciae connect muscles to other muscles. Tendons and muscles work together to move bones.

[image]

The image was taken from the wikipedia link.

Comment: The part of the bone to which the tendon connects is called esthesis

Comment: @CRags you mean enthesis?

Comment: Sorry spelled wrong, you are correct, it's enthesis